# Encrypt/Decrypt string with salt using php7

Tags: php, encryption, php-7, salt, password-hash

I have a string and I want to store this string securely in a database.

So, what came up to my mind is to encrypt this string using a user password as the encryption key.

And when the user needs to use this string we decrypt it using that key.

Is there some algorithm that helps to store these strings in a database securely, preventing anyone accessing it even the team?

Comment: Look over to the right of your screen, under "Related".

Comment: Since php7 many functions deprecated, almost all questions since 5-8 years ago.

Comment: A salt is used to add a known value to a hashed item to prevent the use of rainbow tables when matching hashes. You probably mean that you want to use the user password as an encryption key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use some type of shared secret encryption algorithm like AES.  Both openssl and mcrypt should support this.  I would recommend openssl as mcrypt is EOL.

The following example comes directly from php.net.  You probably don't need the hmac as you want to retrieve the original data.

```
<?php
//$key previously generated safely, ie: openssl_random_pseudo_bytes
$plaintext = "message to be encrypted";
$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
$ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
//$hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, $as_binary=true);
$ciphertext = base64_encode( $iv./*$hmac.*/$ciphertext_raw );

//decrypt later....
$c = base64_decode($ciphertext);
$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
$iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);
//$hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len=32);
$ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen/*+$sha2len*/);
$original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
/*
$calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, $as_binary=true);
if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac))//PHP 5.6+ timing attack safe comparison
{
    echo $original_plaintext."\n";
}
*/
```

Comment: I'm already using these but wanted to know if its secure for sensitive data.

Comment: Its as secure as the encryption algorithm used.  Whether or not that algorithm is good enough depends on your requirements.  You should check with NIST for recommendations on key length / block size etc.  As long as the user is the only one that can decrypt the data and your users password is hashed using @summerSu suggestion it should be secure enough except for brute force cracking considerations.

Comment: What if we encrypted user password(as we are using it as encryption key) before we directly use it as key, for instance, md5 user password so if the user password was weak we avoid any type of brute-force

Comment: And what do you think about using aes-256-cbc as cipher instead of AES-128-CBC AND sha512 instead of 256

Comment: using a larger block size like 256 or 512 would be beneficial.  You should not use the hashed secret.  Your password should be hashed with password_hash and at least bcrypt.  Do not use your own hashing method... I have seen countless fuckups in these "custom implementations."  As long as the password is hashed prompt the user for the password verify it and then decrypt the data with the plain text password in memory.  Every time the user needs to retrieve the data you need them to enter a password.

Comment: As far as brute force goes; you need to enforce good passwords.  Although a lot of the password hashing algorithms support key expansion I would be very cautious assuming that they would provide more entropy.  As long as you are not using the same secret for everyone's data and your passwords are more than 8 chars you should be fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162060/discussion-between-adam-and-alex-barker).